# Unity3D Firebase Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, firebase, unity-game-engine, authentication

In firebase unity3d auth docs, there is a line(Follow instructions for Android and iOS to get an access token for the signed-in Facebook user.)

But in android section of course there is java codes.But in unity, we are using `C#`and I cannot reach `access token` and there is no `FacebookCallBack` and `LoginResult` object in unity SDK.

How can I make Facebook login in Unity with Firebase?

Comment: Any news on the subject? I have the same problem for Google or Twitter login...

Comment: I also have this problem. I don't understand how this is suppose to start.

Answer (score 0):

You should set-up [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/) in you project.
Follow the instructions to configure your Android/iOS app at the developer dashboard.
And after successful log-in you'll receive callback with access token, eg

```
FB.LogInWithReadPermissions (
    new List<string>(){"public_profile", "email", "user_friends"},
    callback: (result) =>{
       Debug.Log("Logged-in successful. Access token: " + result.AccessToken.TokenString)
});
```